# Is it worth caching auth session in client-side state?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, caching, session-state, supabase

I have a React app which uses Supabase for authentication.

I'm wondering, is it best practice to store a user's session in client-side state (e.g. `setState` or the like) in order to avoid making an API call every time a component would like to know if a user is logged in? The `isSignedIn` function on the auth context currently looks like this.

```
isSignedIn: async () => {

  // If there's a valid session object, yes, we're logged in
  if (!!session)
    return true
  
  // If we don't have truthy value for session, check with the server
  // and return appropriately
  let { data } = await client.auth.getSession()

  
  if (!!(data?.session)){
    setSession(data.session)
    return true
  }
}
```

Though the tricky part here is, as long as there's *something* in the `session` state the app considers the user logged in despite the server having potentially ended the session.
It seems to me like this is essentially a cache invalidation issue and I'm leaning toward removing the storing of the session in client-side state. Instead I'll just make an API call every time.

Should I avoid storing the session in app state in favour of making an API call every time, or is my solution just implemented badly?

Also, if all I have now is this async `isSignedIn` function on my auth context, how do I use it? I'm guessing I can't just use it in the render function of, say, for instance a `<ProtectedRoute />` component -

```
return authContext.isSignedIn() ? children : <Navigate to="/sign-in"/>
```

It seems like I'd have to use it within `useEffect`, storing the result in some state of the component which seems like I'm now back at the start (storing the result in some state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended pattern is to use [`onauthstatechange`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange) to update the session in state, e.g. see https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/user-management/react-user-management/src/App.js#L15-L18

```js
 supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
  }, [])
```

Comment: Yes! I also found this after some digging in their doco

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you only need to check for authentication when you interact with the server somehow.

If you make minor UI changes which dont fetch any new data there shouldn't be any reason to make an API call to check for authentication. If your components/code does such a thing its a sign you should rewrite it in a way so it doesn't.

Then again if you're making calls to the server for data or have a genuine reason why the server terminating the session should make the user log out immediately or on an event that otherwise would do something that requires being logged in you should most definitely make the API call.

Comment: Yeah good point. My motivation is, I'm wanting to stay logged in even if I hard refresh. In such a situation client state evaporates, hence calling out to the client API to see if a session is still active (which may or may not call the server).